# Visual Studio 2012 xaml Designer not loading

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012

I turned my computer on today and the following message is displayed on Visual studio 2012. And appears on all my programs, and I am unable to reload the designer on any program. I'm not quite sure what to do as I can't find a solution.

Microsoft.Internal.Assumes+InternalErrorException

Internal error occurred. Additional information: ''.

at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.InPrerequisiteLoop()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImportsStateMachine(PartManager partManager, ComposablePart part)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImports(PartManager partManager, ComposablePart part, Boolean shouldTrackImports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.SatisfyImports(ComposablePart part)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.GetExportedValueFromComposedPart(ImportEngine engine, ComposablePart part, ExportDefinition definition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportedValue(CatalogPart part, ExportDefinition export, Boolean isSharedPart)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.CatalogExport.GetExportedValueCore()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export export)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValuesCore[T](String contractName)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.Marshaler.EnsureMarshalers()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.Marshaler.Marshal[TFrom](TFrom value)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedExportProvider.ComposeExportedValue[T](T value)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.b__6()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re installing the VS update 1.

I found this thread while doing a Google Search :[MSDN Thread](http://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nb-NO/wpf/thread/48132a7a-ced1-4e56-880c-7ad06dc49a64)